# Try-Catch Exception Handling does not provide the correct response

Tags: java, error-handling, exception, try-catch

I'm not sure why when I input anything other than an integer value, the output isn't showing `Invalid Format!`.

That's the exception handling that I'm trying to achieve. Also, how can I close the `Scanner` in a `finally` clause without causing an infinite loop.

```
class ConsoleInput {

public static int getValidatedInteger(int i, int j) {
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numInt = 0;

    while (numInt < i || numInt > j) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Please input an integer between 4 and 19 inclusive: ");
            numInt = scr.nextInt();

            if (numInt < i || numInt > j) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Range!");
            } else {
                throw new InputMismatchException("Invalid Format!");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            scr.next();

        }

    }
    scr.close();
    return numInt;
}
```

This is the output I'm trying to get:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below code will work for you,this is the another approach you can use to get your desire output.
In this code i have handled the InputMismatch in catch block.

```
public static int getValidatedInteger(int i, int j) {
            Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
            int numInt = 0;

            while (numInt < i || numInt > j) {
                try {
                    System.out.print("Please input an integer between 4 and 19 inclusive: ");
                    numInt = scr.nextInt();

                    if (numInt < i || numInt > j) {
                        System.out.println("Incorrect Range!");
                    }

                } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect format!");
                    scr.next();

                }

            }
            scr.close();
            return numInt;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you enter anything other than an int the error will get thrown at the line:

```
 numInt = scr.nextInt();
```

And then get caught in the catch block, thus skipping the print statement. You need to check if there is a next int:

```
if(!scr.hasNextInt()) {
   throw new InputMismatchException("Invalid Format!");
}
```

> Also, how can I close the Scanner in a finally clause without causing an infinite loop.

You do not need to close the `Scanner` in a finally block. In fact, you shouldn't close it at all. It is bad practice to close `System.in`. Generally if you did not open a resource, you should not close it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch InputMismatchException in a separate catch block before Exception catch block and add scr.next(); like following:

```
public static int getValidatedInteger(int i, int j) {
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numInt = 0;

    while (numInt < i || numInt > j) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Please input an integer between 4 and 19 inclusive: ");
            numInt = scr.nextInt();

            if (numInt < i || numInt > j) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Range!");
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Format!");
            scr.next();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            scr.next();

        }

    }
    scr.close();
    return numInt;
}
```